# Capturing a 360 Screenshot in Unity ignores UI Layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Problem: I want to take a 360 Degree Equirectangular screenshot of some Interface Elements in UnityEditor. The tool I found does take 360 screenshots just fine but leaves out Canvas Elements. If I place a cube in my scene it will appear on the screenshot. If I place a canvas in my scene it will not be visible in my screenshot.

Screenshotcontroller looks like this:

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("s"))
        {
            byte[] screenshot = I360Render.Capture( 2048, true, null, true );
            File.WriteAllBytes("D:/screenshot.jpg", screenshot);
        }
    }
```

Actual script executing the screenshot is this one:

```
public static class I360Render
{
    private static Material equirectangularConverter = null;
    private static int paddingX;

    public static byte[] Capture( int width = 1024, bool encodeAsJPEG = true, Camera renderCam = null, bool faceCameraDirection = true )
    {
        if( renderCam == null )
        {
            renderCam = Camera.main;
            if( renderCam == null )
            {
                Debug.LogError( "Error: no camera detected" );
                return null;
            }
        }

        RenderTexture camTarget = renderCam.targetTexture;

        if( equirectangularConverter == null )
        {
            equirectangularConverter = new Material( Shader.Find( "Hidden/I360CubemapToEquirectangular" ) );
            paddingX = Shader.PropertyToID( "_PaddingX" );
        }

        int cubemapSize = Mathf.Min( Mathf.NextPowerOfTwo( width ), 8192 );
        RenderTexture activeRT = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture cubemap = null, equirectangularTexture = null;
        Texture2D output = null;
        try
        {
            cubemap = RenderTexture.GetTemporary( cubemapSize, cubemapSize, 0 );
            cubemap.dimension = UnityEngine.Rendering.TextureDimension.Cube;

            equirectangularTexture = RenderTexture.GetTemporary( cubemapSize, cubemapSize / 2, 0 );
            equirectangularTexture.dimension = UnityEngine.Rendering.TextureDimension.Tex2D;

            if( !renderCam.RenderToCubemap( cubemap, 63 ) )
            {
                Debug.LogError( "Rendering to cubemap is not supported on device/platform!" );
                return null;
            }

            equirectangularConverter.SetFloat( paddingX, faceCameraDirection ? ( renderCam.transform.eulerAngles.y / 360f ) : 0f );
            Graphics.Blit( cubemap, equirectangularTexture, equirectangularConverter );

            RenderTexture.active = equirectangularTexture;
            output = new Texture2D( equirectangularTexture.width, equirectangularTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false );
            output.ReadPixels( new Rect( 0, 0, equirectangularTexture.width, equirectangularTexture.height ), 0, 0 );

            return encodeAsJPEG ? InsertXMPIntoTexture2D_JPEG( output ) : InsertXMPIntoTexture2D_PNG( output );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            Debug.LogException( e );
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            renderCam.targetTexture = camTarget;
            RenderTexture.active = activeRT;

            if( cubemap != null )
                RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary( cubemap );

            if( equirectangularTexture != null )
                RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary( equirectangularTexture );

            if( output != null )
                UnityEngine.Object.DestroyImmediate( output );
        }
    }
```

What is going wrong? Why does this solution seem to ignore UI Elements?

Comment: Hi, Have you tried to play with "layers"? Maybe your tool is screenshotting specific layers and not the UI Classic one

Comment: I tried that, but without success. It's a bug that was already discussed in Unity Forums as I just found out. Read more in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Screen Space - Overlay UI Elements are not normally rendered to the camera. They are rendered directly to the screen. Since your screenshot is based on the camera's texture, you won't capture the Canvas or other UI elements that are rendered directly to the screen.

You can consider changing your canvas to render to Screen Space - Camera. You may have to modify your UI a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My UI Elements are in World Space and they appear on the render texture when I output it to a plane. Sorry, I forgot to mention. Problem is related to Unity's RenderToCubemap function, see my next reply.

Comment: @nrs That makes sense. It does appear to be a bug with the SDK that's been around a long time. Some other solutions mention capturing the UI separately and painting it over your cubemap.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer. This is actually a bug in Unity's 360 Capture SDK that is there for over a year by now related to the RenderToCubemap function. 
There is a hacky workaround [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/support-for-ui-elements-in-rendertocubemap.429201/) in answer #4 and #10. But it will not work for text elements that use TextMesh Pro and causes a performance hit.